# Is there any audio ads for iPhone audio apps?

Tags: iphone, iad, ads

my app is like podcast for web articles.  https://apps.apple.com/app/id1273954643

I plan to make a free version and am curious if there is audio ads for iPhone apps.
Since most users of my app don't see the screen, banner ads doesn't fit well.
I want to insert audio ads like spotify.

I checked http://www.medialets.com/ and http://www.greystripe.com/, but their show cases
are quite vague.  I sent emails to them, but no reply yet.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I am working on an alarm app, users won't spend time inside the application so I am considering audio ads. Just came across your question, it's a bit old, wondering if you can advise what worked best for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... this seems like an awesome business opportunity that hasn't been properly executed yet.

I have also seen mentions of audio ads being served up into client iPhone apps by [TargetSpot](http://www.mobilemarketingwatch.com/targetspot-launches-mobile-ad-platform-to-serve-audio-ads-within-mobile-apps-5516/).

Comment: This company might be the what I wanted to find.  I will check it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I really like your idea.And after searching for a while i came across this helpful tutorial-
Though its kind of commercial but hope it will help you.

http://advertising.about.com/od/smallbusinesscampaigns/a/podcastweb.htm

Answer (score 1):

if you're willing to use an API. You could use something like this
https://docs.api.audio/recipes/programmatic-audio-ads

````py
#Check that you are using python 3.8 or further 
#pip install -U aflr
import aflr

aflr.api_key = "APIKEY"

audience = [
    {"number": "33", "location": "Buckingham"},
    {"number": "22", "location": "Sunshine"},
]
text = """
    <<soundSegment::effect1>>
    <<sectionName::hello>> 
    If you have any plans for today, cancel them! 
    <<soundSegment::intro>>
    <<sectionName::hello2>>
    This really is the final call for {{location}} Hyundai's massive clear out sale! Only until midnight tonight, so come on down!
    <<soundSegment::main>>
    <<sectionName::main>> 
    We're clearing out all remaining 2020 Hyundais at Ottawa's top volume Hyundai dealers. These are the last days for clear out pricing and amazing clear out incentives. Zero percent financing for up to 84 months, and up to 7700 in cash price adjustments on all 2020 Hyundais at Hyundai on {{location}}. Pick one of the {{number}} Santa Fays in stock, a family-sized SUV with all-wheel drive and back-up cameras from just $85 weekly, zero down!
    It's the easiest time to get into a new Hyundai, but these deals won't be around for long, ONLY until midnight TONIGHT! 
    <<soundSegment::outro>>
    <<sectionName::outro>>
    Get into a new Hyundai today. At {{location}} Hyundai, better cars for passionate car drivers. <break time="1s"/>
"""
script = aflr.Script().create(scriptText=text, scriptName="helloworld", moduleName="hello", projectName="hello")
print(script)
for item in audience:
    r = aflr.Speech().create(
        scriptId=script.get("scriptId"),
        voice="en-US-GuyNeural",
        speed=120,
        silence_padding=0,
        audience=[item],
    )
    print(r)
    template = "hotwheels"
    print(template)
for item in audience:
    r = aflr.Mastering().create(
        scriptId=script.get("scriptId"), soundTemplate=template, audience=[item]
    )
    print(r)
    url = aflr.Mastering().download(
        scriptId=script.get("scriptId"),
        parameters=item,
        destination=".",
    )
    print(f"✨ Mastered file for template {template} ✨")
    print(url)
    ```
That way you could serve this, this is in python. You could also do it in Swift (but there's no sdk for this atm you'd need to write it yourself).

Disclamier - I work for www.api.audio
````